# How to send app invite using android studio

Tags: android

I need to send app invitation message from my app to friends via whatsapp,facebook,hike,... with the message and playstore link.I have seen this kind of invitations in other apps like hike,whatscall,... like the
[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwD0c.jpg)

I want to send exactly the same kind of message with the playstore link and app logo for my app also and it should be shared using all the available sharing option in users mobile.In my application i have included a inform friends menu and on clicking on that this function should work.I have seen firebase app invite examples but it needs google-services.json and i think it will only send text message from users email,I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending text msg or image or both via app can be done using Action_send intent. The following code should work for your requirement.

```
void shareImageWithText(){
    Uri contentUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/drawable/" + "ic_launcher");

    StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
    msg.append("Hey, Download this awesome app!");
    msg.append("\n");
    msg.append("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=Your_Package_Name"); //example :com.package.name

    if (contentUri != null) {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // temp permission for receiving app to read this file
        shareIntent.setType("*/*");
        shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg.toString());
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
        try {
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No App Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to send an image from server directly (without keeping image in resources)?